# Wait For Second Script to trigger till all background parallel process of second Script finishes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two script. Second is dependent on First. But first script has background process so second invokes without completion all background process of First Script.Is there anyway to wait or stop second script till all background processes of first script completes.I am adding sample code below:

```
#!/bin/sh <br>
# This is First Script! 
echo script 1 start here        # This is a comment, too! 

for number in 1 2 3 4 5 
do 
echo $number &  # Here five backgroud process triggers
done 

echo Script one ends here 

#!/bin/sh  
# This is Second Script! 
echo Script 2 starts    </t># This is a comment, too! 

for number in 1 2 3 4 5 
do 
echo $number &   # here other five background process triggers 
done 
echo Script 2 ends here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $! to record the pids of any background process and use it to determine execution point of your secondary script.

<strike>Your original script lists sh, wait is a function of bash. If possible use bash.</strike> Functions exist in sh

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm Starting Now"
sleep 60 &  #this process now executes in the bg
bg_pid=$!
wait $bg_pid #this will pause the script until pid is dead.
echo "You will not see this until sleep is complete"
```

To incorporate this into the script you posted it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# This is First Script! 
echo 'script 1 start here'        # This is a comment, too! 

for number in 1 2 3 4 5 
do 
  echo $number &  # Here five background process triggers
  declare bgpid[$number]=$! #we will pack all the pids into an array
done 

wait ${bgpid[@]} #this exposes the array to wait
echo 'Script one ends here' 
#Call next script
```

Comment: What about loop ? Also $! saves last running pid ?

Comment: Yes, $! returns pid of the last executed command. If you are passing multiple items as bg processes and they will terminate asynchronously you would need to pass each pid to wait. wait can accept multiple arguments.

Comment: If this helped or otherwise was correct I'd appreciate the upvote and answer tag :).

Comment: Also highlighting wait ${bgpid[@]} in sh worked perfectly fine.